# Pyspark GroupBy Flatten row

Tags: pyspark, group-by

I have been trying to flatten the row in pyspark dataframe after a group by
My dataset looks like this

```
|member_id|age|gender|      date|cost|
+---------+---+------+----------+-----------+
|        1| 35|  Male|2023-10-01|        200|
|        1| 35|  Male|2023-10-02|        210|
|        2| 28|Female|2023-10-01|        150|
|        2| 28|Female|2023-10-02|        160|
+---------+---+------+----------+-----------+
```

Now what I want as the output is:

```
[
    [
       [1,35, Male, 2023-10-01, 200],[1, 35, Male, 2023-10-02, 210]
    ],
    [
       [2, 28, Female, 2023-10-01, 150],[2, 28, Female, 2023-10-01, 160]
    ]
]
```

I have tried to achieve this but I ain't able to.

Comment: what did you try that did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Idea :

First collect all columns into a list by `F.array` function

and

do a `F.collect_list` on a `groupBy`.

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data1 = [

[1, 35,"Male","2023-10-01",200],
[1, 35,"Male","2023-10-02",210],
[2, 28,"Female","2023-10-01",150],
[2, 28,"Female","2023-10-02",160],

]

columns =["member_id", "age", "gender", "date", "cost"]

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=columns)

df1.show(n=10, truncate=False)
print("Collect columns into list")
df2 = df1.withColumn("colList", F.array(*df1.columns))
df2.show(n=10, truncate=False)
print("collect_list on the groupBy")
df3 = df2.groupBy("member_id").agg(F.collect_list(F.col("colList")))
df3.show(n=10, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
+---------+---+------+----------+----+
|member_id|age|gender|date      |cost|
+---------+---+------+----------+----+
|1        |35 |Male  |2023-10-01|200 |
|1        |35 |Male  |2023-10-02|210 |
|2        |28 |Female|2023-10-01|150 |
|2        |28 |Female|2023-10-02|160 |
+---------+---+------+----------+----+

Collect columns into list
+---------+---+------+----------+----+--------------------------------+
|member_id|age|gender|date      |cost|colList                         |
+---------+---+------+----------+----+--------------------------------+
|1        |35 |Male  |2023-10-01|200 |[1, 35, Male, 2023-10-01, 200]  |
|1        |35 |Male  |2023-10-02|210 |[1, 35, Male, 2023-10-02, 210]  |
|2        |28 |Female|2023-10-01|150 |[2, 28, Female, 2023-10-01, 150]|
|2        |28 |Female|2023-10-02|160 |[2, 28, Female, 2023-10-02, 160]|
+---------+---+------+----------+----+--------------------------------+

collect_list on the groupBy
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|member_id|collect_list(colList)                                               |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1        |[[1, 35, Male, 2023-10-01, 200], [1, 35, Male, 2023-10-02, 210]]    |
|2        |[[2, 28, Female, 2023-10-01, 150], [2, 28, Female, 2023-10-02, 160]]|
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```